# finding header files for simple device driver in Fedora 20

Tags: c++, linux, linux-device-driver, fedora

So, I've tried following the simple examples to load a "Hello World" device driver found in the O'Rielly Linux Device Drivers manual.  The problem is that for some reason it won't work unless I explicitly define the path for my header files in the include statements; i.e. I must type `#include </usr/src/kernels/3.19.8-100.fc20.i686+PAE/include/linux/init.h>` instead of just `#include </linux/init.h>`

here is my makefile

```
obj-m := hello.o
KDIR =/usr/src/kernels/3.19.8-100.fc20.i686+PAE/include
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean
```

and it returns a can't find error on all header files unless explicitly defined as `#include </usr/src/kernels/3.19.8-100.fc20.i686+PAE/include/linux/init.h>` which I'd rather not have to do.

Thanks for your help.

In case it helps anyone, if I keep in the explicit include statements and then compile, the hello.mod.c file that results is as follows.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/vermagic.h>
#include <linux/compiler.h>

MODULE_INFO(vermagic, VERMAGIC_STRING);

__visible struct module __this_module
__attribute__((section(".gnu.linkonce.this_module"))) = {
    .name = KBUILD_MODNAME,
    .init = init_module,
#ifdef CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD
    .exit = cleanup_module,
#endif
    .arch = MODULE_ARCH_INIT,
};

static const char __module_depends[]
__used
__attribute__((section(".modinfo"))) =
"depends=";
```

This loads fine using insmod.

Comment: Just to check something, what does `uname -r` returns?

Comment: it returns the correct kernel version.   I've shortened it above, but the one I'm using in my explicit include statements match what I have in the KDIR line in the makefile which both match the uname -r call.    I guess it doesn't hurt to list the full kernel version, it's 3.19.8-100.fc20.i686+PAE.   I've edited my original question to include this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler should have an option to specify the includes' search path. GnuCC (`gcc`, `g++`) and CLang (`clang`, `clang++`) both use `-I`.

If your header file is at `/usr/src/kernels/3.19.8-100/include/linux/init.h` and you invoke, let say `g++` with:

```
g++ -I /usr/src/kernels/3.19.8-100/include/ source.cpp
```

Then `source.cpp` can `#include <linux/init.h>`.

---

Now, you need to learn how to provide that command line option to your compiler through the OS makefiles to build modules. This is documented at several places, but the usual is to define an environment variable `CPPFLAGS` containing the additional options:

```
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I /usr/src/kernels/3.19.8-100/include/"
$ make
```

Comment: So, I tried setting CFLAGS, but I'm still getting the same error.   I used export CFLAGS='-I /usr/src/kernels/....../include/"    and make still gave an error.    Any other ideas?    And thanks for the quick response

Comment: This was the most helpful answer, though I had to do a few other things as listed in my own answer below.   
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> KDIR =/usr/src/kernels/3.19.8-100.fc20.i686+PAE/include

I think your "KDIR line" is wrong .... This Makefile works (usually) :

```
obj-m    := hello.o
KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD    := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Assume `# dnf install kernel kernel-devel` → I.e. the `kernel-devel` must be an exact match for `kernel`.

**Note**: /lib/modules/[version]/{*build*}/ is a link to `/usr/src/kernels/[version]/`, **not** to /usr/src/kernels/[version]/include/ .... The link is created at the install of `kernel-devel`

Comment: Thanks.   I set up the makefile as specified, but the error persists.    The path to the include headers are just not found unless explicitly defined.     I think that the kernel-devel matches the kernel, but I'll look to that next.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  Thanks to YSC who pointed me on the right path.   I just needed to do some extra things found here [Where Does GCC Look to Find its Header Files?](http://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art026)

Basically, I needed to add the include directory to gcc's header include path.   I did this by typing `cpp -I <desired path> -v` which for me was /usr/src/kernels/.......etc.

running just `cpp -v` gave me a list of the include paths gcc searches.   just make sure it's in there.

so now my driver modules build correctly and load with the the include statements as `#include <linux/init.h>` just as I wanted.